# Count mutual followers in a relation table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a pandas DataFrame like so:

```
   from_user  to_user
0        123      456
1        894      135
2        179      890
3        456      123
```

Where each row contains two IDs that reflect whether the `from_user` "follows" the `to_user`. How can I count the total number of mutual followers in the DataFrame using pandas?

In the example above, the answer should be 1 (users 123 & 456).

Comment: this sounds like a network problem, I don't know if `pandas` is the best approach here

Comment: You're probably right. I'm just working through some traditional SQL problems using pandas as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use MultiIndex set operations:

```
In [11]: i1 = df.set_index(["from_user", "to_user"]).index

In [12]: i2 = df.set_index(["to_user", "from_user"]).index

In [13]: (i1 & i2).levels[0]
Out[13]: Int64Index([123, 456], dtype='int64')
```

To get the count you have to divide the length of this index by 2:

```
In [14]: len(i1 & i2) // 2
Out[14]: 1
```

Comment: Wow. This is awesome and totally worked. I'll mark this as the answer in 2 minutes!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do is to `concat` the values and `sort` them as string.
Then count how many times the values occur:

```
# concat the values as string type
df['concat'] = df.from_user.astype(str) + df.to_user.astype(str)

# sort the string values of the concatenation
df['concat'] = df.concat.apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)))

# count the occurences of each and substract 1
count = (df.groupby('concat').size() -1).sum()

Out[64]: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another slightly more hacky way to do this:

```
df.loc[df.to_user.isin(df.from_user)]
  .assign(hacky=df.from_user * df.to_user)
  .drop_duplicates(subset='hacky', keep='first')
  .drop('hacky', 1)

   from_user  to_user
0        123      456
```

The whole multiplication hack exists to ensure we don't return `123 --> 456` and `456 --> 123` since both are valid given the conditional we provide to `loc`